# How do I query across child and parent fields using a multimatch type query in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Example:

```
Parent doc
    id: 1
    field1: politics
    field2: donkeys
Child doc
    parent_id: 1
    field1: prose
```

I would like to be able to search for the words 'politics donkey prose' (as an AND query, but not caring which fields any of the words match) and have it match the parent document. Is this possible? Or do I need to start rolling up the children as a big field within the parent (very undesirable because there can be many children)?

I am preferably looking for the solution in Java, but I will take it any way I can get it!

Comment: Do you, also, want to match something like "politics donkey" and still get a result (because those can be found in the parent)? The same goes for returning the document if you search for "prose" only (it matches the child)?

Comment: And you need to match ALL of them, no exception, right?

Comment: Yes and yes. I would like to treat it like a multimatch query where all terms are ANDed, but it just doesn't matter where they match.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do it:

```
String parent_fields = "f1,f2";
String child_fields = "f3,f4";
BoolQueryBuilder allQueries = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

for( String term : terms )
{
    BoolQueryBuilder booly = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    for( String field : parent_fields.split( "," ) )
    {
        booly.should( QueryBuilders.termQuery( field, term ) );
    }
    for( String field : child_fields.split( "," ) )
    {
        booly.should( QueryBuilders.topChildrenQuery( child_type, QueryBuilders.termQuery( field, term )  ) );
    }
    allBoolies.must( booly );
}
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not convinced this is possible. Simply because, there's no way to correlate which terms match in the parent with the ones left to match in children.

Comment: I am using it and I think it translates to this:

Searching for terms t1,t2 --

(f1:t1 OR f2:t1 OR f3:t1 OR f4:t1) AND (f1:t2 OR f2:t2 OR f3:t2 OR f4:t2)

Which meets my strict requirements, but it makes any complex querying hard (such as using string searches). Thoughts?